# forkOS_entry: interrupted error: what is this?

Tags: haskell

I'm getting this error printed to stdout when I test run a  Haskell program I'm working on. It happens sometimes, not all the time, on identical runs of the program.

```
forkOS_entry: interrupted
```

There is a line in the program that calls `mask_ $ forkIO` to start another thread. I think the error is coming from that thread. Is there a way I can get a better error message or somehow suppress this error message? What is going on? The program seems to run fine regardless.

`_ <- mask_ $ forkIO $ mapSSL cafilePath (icSSLWrapPort c) (icHostname c) (icPort c)`

Answer (score 1):

I would check the [async](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html) package for relevant functions. After stumbling upon the async package, I found the functions to be a bit more reliable to use for my tests. Specifically, the function that might help in this case would be

```
waitCatch :: Async a -> IO (Either SomeException a)
```

The [Marlow book](http://www.rakuten.com/prod/parallel-and-concurrent-programming-in-haskell/249608971.html?listingId=-1&s_kwcid=) is a great reference for understanding the concurrency package. I hope that the reference helps. 
If you can paste a small sample code that I can test with, I might be able to post tested code.