# Haskell Array.Accelerate - forkOS error

Tags: haskell, plot, gnuplot, gpu

Trying to plot the output of some `Data.Array.Accelerate` computations with `gnuplot` I encountered a strange problem. When run via the interpreter everything is fine, as is plotting straight Haskell data or just printing the Accelerate values, however trying to plot the Accelerate data fails. The error given is `forkOS_entry: interrupted`.

I've since realised I should just be more UNIXy and do one thing (well) in each program. But I'm interested in finding out why this fails. I include a minimum code sample below.

```
import Prelude hiding (zip,zipWith)

import Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple
import Data.Array.Accelerate
-- import Data.Array.Accelerate.Interpreter
import Data.Array.Accelerate.CUDA

f :: Vector Float -> Vector Float -> Acc (Vector Float)
f xs ys = let xs' = use xs
              ys' = use ys
          in
             (zipWith (*) xs' ys')
n=10::Int

points = toList.run $ f (fromList (Z:.n) [1..10]) (fromList (Z:.n) [-5..4])

main = plotList [] points
```

**update 2014/09/11**

Based on `user2141650`'s suggestion (thanks!) changing the last line to

```
plotList [] $! points
```

fixes the problem. In fact it makes the plot actually appear, whereas without this the program would finish with or without error but would never actually display the plot. I suppose I'd accept this as an answer if it was written up, but it would still be nice to know what's going on.

Possibly related:

- [forkOS_entry: interrupted error: what is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554008/forkos-entry-interrupted-error-what-is-this)

(By the way, please stop trying to edit for grammar. There isn't anything wrong with the question as is, I am a native speaker and write exactly what I mean. Thank you for your contribution though.)

Comment: Something to try: recompile with `-threaded`. (Don't forget to make a trivial edit to your source code so ghc thinks it's worth its while.)

Comment: The GHC flag -fforce-recomp comes in handy when messing with compiler flags.

Comment: @SeanD Did you try it?

Comment: @enoughreptocomment Sorry about the delay, I was away from my GPU box this week. Interestingly using `-threaded` makes it run successflly about 1/4 of the time, otherwise it just fails with the same error. It feels like there's some sort of race condition going on, I don't know if that's a bug with either of the libraries or GHC .


*edit*: to make matters more confusing I've noticed that the error only seems to occur when I use `runghc` rather than `ghc` and the program directly.

Comment: Have you tried to strace the execution?  Give it a go, a trace of a failing run should be quite illuminating.  You may need the flag to follow through fork() calls.

Comment: Could it be that gnuplot and accelerate are interfering with one another? Could you try fully evaluating `points` before calling plotList?

Comment: @AndrewMcGregor I tried `strace`ing successful and unsuccessful runs, but there was nothing that jumped out at me (not that I'm so familiar with reading them), I can post them if you think they'd be interesting.   @user2141650 see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, this is likely because of the interleaved interaction of gnuplot and accelerate on the GPU, when the accelerate computation is called lazily. I can't say I know the details, but this [0] seems relevant. It may be that gnuplot can't use the GPU since Accelerate has already claimed it, but Accelerate won't release it until fully evaluated. Or else that gnuplot claims the GPU *before* Accelerate. Hairy-looking issue, and it might warrant a mention in the github issue tracker for Accelerate.

[0] https://github.com/AccelerateHS/accelerate/issues/48